# Can I remove duplicate lines from a report?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, duplicate-management

Our marketing division wants a report of everyone involved in our conferences. I am able to get this with a report that looks at contacts, opportunities (tied to conferences in a given year), and opportunity products (payment for talks and travel). The problem is that most people have multiple talks at a given conference.

I end up with something like this and would like to remove the duplicates. Each Contact has 1 or more opportunity (but we are only accessing one per contact) and each opportunity has 1 or more opportunity products. I am using a custom report type (Contact-Opportunity (primary contact)-Products).

```
Name        Team        Phone Number
William B   2016 Team   [Phone Number]
William B   2016 Team   [Phone Number]
Michael B   2016 Team   [Phone Number]
Michael B   2016 Team   [Phone Number]
Michael B   2016 Team   [Phone Number]
```

Comment: are you going to show only these columns or some other columns including these columns?

Comment: Depends on what marketing actually decides. Right now I heard these (maybe not team) and possible email, but they may want more details. Between 3 and 6 columns, probably.

Comment: I've had similar challenges before and ended up using Conga Composer that outputted the SFDC report to an excel template that included a pivot table. This is a reasonably priced appexchange offering excellent customer support.

Comment: We already use come Conga (not actually sure which) so I'll look into this. My current solution is to export to Excel and clean up by hand.